# hide/reappear of a toolbar

Tags: objective-c, ios7

in my app, i'm hiding the toolbar and then put it back to it's previous place. the animation goes downwards. on iOS 6, the animation goes well, in ios 7 the animation is good as well but when i set the toolbar to opaque, a gray bar stays int he background where the bar was and the bar hides. how can i get rid of that gray bar? here's the code i'm using for hiding:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^{
    self.navigationController.toolbar.center = CGPointMake(self.navigationController.toolbar.center.x, self.navigationController.toolbar.center.y + self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.height);
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    self.navigationController.toolbar.hidden = YES;
}];
```